# linking files to html that are in a different sub-directory to get rid of the .html or .php extension

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

ok so I have just recently changed my directory to exclude the .html extensions.

I have linked files by using a "/" for e.g "/mackbyte_files/style.css" as cited here [How to link html pages in same or different folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908765/how-to-link-html-pages-in-same-or-different-folders)

this works fine once all the files are uploaded to the server, however when i open up the index.html page on the computers directory all the css and linked files are not displaying.

Is there a way I can get best of both worlds so i can make changes to the page locally and view them to test the changes etc and then upload them?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? This is very vague, I don't see how anyone can answer that without code. Maybe your css sheets aren't linked properly? You can link your CSS sheets using the same method too.