# How I can do this on html

Tags: html, hyperlink, directory

I have a website and I've been searching a lot for this question and can't find anything yet.

Anyone knows how to make links take you to another folder and show the html page without page in URL? Example:

I have a html page called service.html and its on folder /service. I want a link to take me there without displaying in the URL my html file like:

```html
<a href="www.example/service/">click me</a>
```

And it takes you to the html file and shows your content without displaying the html name in the URL. just www.example/service/ :D

Comment: The easiest way would be to rename the file `index.html` which will usually be automatically served?

Comment: Search for URL rewriting http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: I tried that but its forbidden.

Comment: is `.htaccess` forbidden as well?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the file `index.html` instead of `service.html` should work, if the website is currently hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method @tasteslikejava mentioned, or you can create a `.htaccess` in the services directory and put in the following information:

```
DirectoryIndex service.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
<a href="name_of_folder/service.html">link</a>
```

[How to link html pages in same or different folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908765/how-to-link-html-pages-in-same-or-different-folders)

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned: "I want a link to take me there **without displaying the url my html file**"