# select file directory path? html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, directory, path

I want to include files in my html doc.

If for example the html doc is inside a folder1 with another folder2 which has a file I want to acces its simply /folder2/file .
What If the html doc is inside a folder2 which is inside a folder1, in which there is another folder3 , in which I want to access the file?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908765/how-to-link-html-pages-in-same-or-different-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`../` is used to go one step behind the current directory that is your case which is folder1.From there go to folder3 and access the file.

Use `../folder3/file`

Comment: super thanks =) I guess If I want to go 2 folders back its just ../../folder3/file